# Finding the solution to a second order ordinary differential equation where one solution is already known

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem is from the book "Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations" by
Shepley L. Ross. Below is my solution to the problem, which I believe is wrong. In any case,
it does not match the answer in the book. I am hoping somebody here can tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob
Problem:
Given that $y = e^{2x}$ is a solution of
$$ (2x+1)y'' - 4(x+1)y' + 4y = 0$$
find a linearly independent solution by reducing the order. Write the general solution.
Answer:
Let $f(x)$ represent the solution we have.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) &=& e^{2x} \\
y &=& f(x) v = e^{2x}v \\
y' &=& e^{2x} v' + 2ve^{2x} \\
y'' &=& e^{2x} v'' + 2e^{2x}v' + 4ve^{2x} + 2v'e^{2x} \\
y'' &=& e^{2x} v'' + 4e^{2x}v' + 4ve^{2x} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x+1)(e^{2x} v'' + 4e^{2x}v' + 4ve^{2x}) - 4(x+1)(e^{2x} v' + 2ve^{2x}) + 4e^{2x}v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' + 4v) - 4(x+1)( v' + 2v) + 4v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' + 4v) - 4(x+1)( v') - 4(x+1)(2v) + 4v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' + 4v) - 4(x+1)( v') - 8xv - 8v + 4v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' + 4v) - 4(x+1)( v') - 8xv - 4v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)(v'' + 4v' + 4v) + (2x+1)(4v)- 4(x+1)( v') - 8xv - 4v &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' + 4v) - 4(x+1)( v') - 8xv - 4v &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' ) - 4(x+1)( v') &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'' + 4v' ) - 4x( v') - 4 v' &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'') + (2x+1)(4v' ) - 4x( v') - 4 v' &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)( v'') + 4xv' &=& 0 \\
(2x+1)v''+ 4xv' &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $w = \frac{dv}{dx}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x+1)\frac{dw}{dx} + 4xw &=& 0 \\
\frac{dw}{w} + \frac{dx}{2x+1} &=& 0 \\
\int \frac{dw}{w} \,\, dx + \int \frac{dx}{2x+1} \,\, dx &=& \int 0 \,\, dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now to perform this integration:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{2x+1} \,\, dx $$
we use the substitution $u_1 = 2x + 1$ which gives $du_1 = dx$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
2x &=& u_1 - 1 \\
4x &=& 2u_1 - 2 \\
\int \frac{dx}{2x+1} \,\, dx &=& \int \frac{2u_1-2}{u_1} \,\, du_1 =
\int 2 \,\, du_1 - \int \frac{2}{u_1} \,\, du_1 \\
\int \frac{dx}{2x+1} \,\, dx &=& 2(2x+1) - 2 \ln{|2x+1|} + C_1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln{|w|} + 2(2x+1) - 2 \ln{|2x+1|} + C_1 &=& 0 \\
\ln{|w|} + \ln{e^{(4x+2)}} - 2 \ln{|2x+1|} + C_1 &=& 0 \\
\ln{\bigg|\frac{we^{(4x+2)}}{(2x+1)^2}\bigg|} &=& -C_1 \\
\frac{we^{(4x+2)}}{(2x+1)^2} &=& C_2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
w &=& \frac{dv}{dx} = C_2 \left( \frac{(2x+1)^2}{e^{(4x+2)}} \right) =
   C_2 \left( \frac{(2x+1)^2}{e^{2x+1}e^{2x+1}} \right) \\
dv &=&  \frac{C_2(2x+1)^2}{e^{2x+1}e^{2x+1}} \, dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Using an online integral calcuator, we find:
$$ \int \frac{(2x+1)^2}{e^{2x+1}e^{2x+1}} \,\, dx = -\frac{(8x^2+12+5)e^{-4x-2}}{8} + C_3 $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
v &=& -\frac{C_2(8x^2+12+5)e^{-4x-2}}{8} + C_3 \\ 
v &=& e^{-2x}y \\
e^{-2x}y  &=& -\frac{C_2(8x^2+12+5)e^{-4x-2}}{8} + C_3 \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
However, the book's answer is:
$$ y = c_1e^{2x} + c_2(x+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point
$$(2x+1)\frac{dw}{dx} + 4xw = 0 
$$
you missed to transfer the factor $4x$ to the next step. It should be
$$
\frac{dw}{w} + \frac{4x\,dx}{2x+1} = 0 ,
$$
so that then
\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{w} + 2\,dx -\frac{2\,dx}{2x+1} &= 0 \\
\implies
\ln|w|+2x-\ln|2x+1|&=c,\\
v'=w&=Ce^{-2x}(2x+1),\\
v&=-Ce^{-2x}(x+1),\\
y=e^{2x}v&=-C(x+1)
\end{align}

Then, after this factor miraculously re-appears in the discussion of the $u_1$ substitution, you simply replaced $dx$ with $du_1$, while the correct formula is $u_1=2x+1\implies du_1=2\,dx$.

This reduction by a factor then exponent $2$ then also decreases the complexity in the ensuing computations.

---

(Btw., the `eqnarray` environment was declared obsolete decades ago. Use `align` and related environments. Read the official `l2tabu` guide in the LaTeX2e documentation.)